# Wrapping groups of adjacent siblings

Tags: jquery, word-wrap, siblings

I need to wrap different groupings of adjactent sibling divs within tables based on certain class values.  The HTML markup can vary but here is an example...

```
<div class="grid-4">4</div>
<div class="grid-4">4</div>
<div class="grid-4">4</div>
<div class="grid-4">4</div>
<div class="grid-8">8</div>
<div class="grid-8">8</div>
<div class="grid-4">4</div>
<div class="grid-4">4</div>
<div class="grid-8">8</div>
<div class="grid-4">4</div>
<div class="grid-4">4</div>
<div class="grid-4">4</div>
```

Here are the different groupings:

1. one grid-8 and one grid-4
2. one grid-4 and one grid-8
3. three grid-4
4. whatever is left

I have code for #1 and #2 that seems to work but my code for #3 does not include the third grid-4 within the wrapping. I suspect I may be misunderstanding the adjactent sibling selector.

This fiddle shows what I have so far:  http://jsfiddle.net/92cmytw9/1/

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you possibly show the html you intend for the JavaScript to create, because your numbered descriptions are difficult - for me - to understand.

Comment: And show your Javascript code here, not just as a jsfiddle link. Why don't you use a stack snippet instead of jsfiddle? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0

Comment: Are you sure the order of your code in your fiddle isn't a factor?

Comment: `div.grid-4 + div.grid-4 + div.grid-4` selects the _first_ DIV in the group of 3, not the last. So you should be using `.next()`, not `.prev()`.

Comment: @Barmar, it selects the last DIV.  See http://jsfiddle.net/3h6h8u9w/

Comment: @ j08691 Yes, the order of the code does play a factor in the result but the 1, 2, 3, 4 order I listed will produce the desired result most of the time for my purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have good working solutions for #1 and #2:

```
$('#container').find('div.grid-4 + div.grid-8').each(function () {
  $(this)
    .prev()
    .andSelf()
    .wrapAll('<table width="100%"><tr><td></td></tr></table>')
    .attr('class', '');
});
```

`andSelf()` is deprecated, so use **[`addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addback/)** instead.

You can simplify it a bit:

```
$('#container div.grid-4 + div.grid-8').each(function () {
  $(this)
    .prev()
    .addBack()
    .wrapAll('<table width="100%"><tr><td>')
    .attr('class', '');
});
```

The `table` elements will automatically be closed for you.

---

#3 is a bit tricky.  You can't create the collection and process `each` member of it, because some groups of three will overlap other groups of three.

Instead, you could use a `while` loop, and keep processing the *first* group of three until there are no more.  `prevUntil(':not(div.grid-4)')` grabs everything that's needed:

```
var f4;
while(f4=$('#container div.grid-4 + div.grid-4 + div.grid-4').first(), f4.length) {
  f4.prevUntil(':not(div.grid-4)')
    .addBack()
    .wrapAll('<table width="100%"><tr><td>')
    .attr('class', '');
}
```

---

#4 is more straightforward:

```
$('#container > div').wrap('<table width="100%"><tr><td>');
```

---

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/83sLgtps/2)

Click the buttons at top to see the effects.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions, they work very nicely for my needs. I haven't seen the construct for #3 before so I learned something new. Also, thanks for pointing out that addBack() replaces andSelf(). I forgot to change the code after reading the jQuery docs.